# Using a while loop to iterate trough a list but i cant get the item after "150"

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement, while-loop

The while loop need to iterate trough the list and get the number thats divisible by five, If the number is greater than 150, then skip it and move to the next, If the number is greater than 500, then stop the loop.

```
list = [12, 75, 150, 180, 145, 525, 50]
i = 0
length = len(list)

while i < length:
    if list[i] > 500:
        break
    
    elif list[i] > 150:
        continue
    
    elif list[i] % 5 == 0:
        print(list[i])
    
    i+=1
```

Comment: Condsider using: `for i in alist: if i > 500: break; if i <= 150 and i % 5 == 0: print(i)` Note, I changed `list` to `alist` because you should not use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: @Max-Benen dont forget to close your question by validating the anwer you prefer, its the way SO is functional

Answer (score 4):

you dont increment i when item > 150, so

modify

```
elif list[i] > 150:
    continue
```

by

```
elif list[i] > 150:
    i+= 1
    continue
```

or

```
elif list[i] > 150:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [12, 75, 150, 180, 145, 525, 50]
i = 0
length = len(list)

while i < length:
    if list[i] > 500:
        pass
    
    elif list[i] > 150:
        pass
    
    elif list[i] % 5 == 0:
        print(list[i])
    
    i+=1
```

Output:

75
150
145
50

Or if you want it to exit when 525 comes up then change `pass` to `break` in the if statement.

```
if list[i] > 500:
    break
```

Output:

75
150
145